# How do I take input from a user and pass it back to the controller in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been able to create a link that a user can click that will trigger a csv file to be downloaded to the user's computer.

My next hurdle is having two fields for the entering of start and end dates. When the user fills these fields and clicks the download button, I need to edit what is entered into the downloaded csv with only the items with values between those two dates.

My code right now inside the html.erb:

```
    <% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.ready(function(){
      ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize({
        title: "Home",
        icon: "<%= asset_path('favicon.ico') %>"
      });
    });
  </script>
<% end %>

<h1>Orders</h1>

<form> 
  Edit date information to download specific range. Default is all available orders. <br>
  Start Date: <input type="date" name="start_date" value="MM/DD/YYYY">
  End Date: <input type="date" name="end_date" value="MM/DD/YYYY"> <br>
  Download: <%= link_to "CSV", orders_path(format: "csv") %>
</form>

<table>
 #code for generating a table, too much to just paste here
</table>
```

The link_to following the Download: is what I know works just fine for downloading the csv, but cannot now figure out how to get the two dates information.

I have a respond_to inside the controller:

```
@csv_order = Order.new
    respond_to do |format|
      params.each { |key, value| puts "#{key} is #{value}" }
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @csv_order.to_csv(@CSV_data, params[:start_date], params[:end_date]) }
    end
```

From the best information that I could find, the data entered by the user is supposed to be returned within the params hash, for which I added as shown above. But having created the params.each to check that the start and end date fields exist, they are not present.

I also found information about passing the values from the html.erb directly to the method in the order.rb. I simply copied and pasted the example just to test it working and edit it from there. However, the form item doesn't even show up on the web page. This one is the most frustrating, because it's likely something completely inane that I'm overlooking or ignorant about.

The copied code put into the html.erb:

```
<% form_tag(:action => 'search') do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "SearchInput" %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

With the search method in the order.rb:

```
def search
    puts "testing"
    puts params["SearchInput"]
  end
```

My question is: how can I get the information entered by the user (start_date and end_date) to be used by my code to edit what orders are put into the csv for downloading? What do I need to change, or what am I missing/overlooking, to get this to work?

Thank you greatly.

Comment: We need to see the actual `.erb` where you create your form and solicit start and end dates in order to determine why that data isn't making it into your params hash.

Comment: one way is to create a `form` with `method: :get`

Comment: There's not much more to the .erb than I had originally pasted, but I edited the code in the question.

Comment: Anyone got any suggestions?